# set number of comments per page

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm using `get_comments()` in one of my page to retrive a list of comments.
However, I want only four comment to be in one page, so if there are 12 comment, they will be divide to three pages, and load the next page with ajax.
I couldn't find any `comments_per_page` or something similar in the function [get_comments()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

Any idea how to achive this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using [wp_list_comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) with the parameter `per_page` did the job.